# call method from another class when button in pop up window is pressed

Tags: java, android

I have this code in `Dialog` class:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("MyTitle")
            .setMessage("MyMessage")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      /////////LINE OF MY QUESTION/////////////////////
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

and I need to call method "OK_Clicked" from another class (`MainActivity`) inside `OnClickListener for` "OK" button (`///LINE OF MY QUESTION///`). I have tried it with:

```
MainActivity xyz = new MainActivity();
xyz.OK_Clicked();
```

But every time when I click "OK" button, the app just crashes saying: "MyApp has stopped."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` outside of where you need it (as in, assign it to a class level variable) and then create a method for calling its `onClick` method from outside the class.

```
//Just take your existing anonymous subclass definitions and put them here
private DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener1 = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            };
private DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener2 = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            }

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("MyTitle")
            .setMessage("MyMessage")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", listener1)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", listener2);
    return builder.create();
}

// Call these methods from outside this class
public void onClick1(){
    listener1.onClick();
}

public void onClick2(){
    listener2.onClick();
}
```